# Hibernate map to views

Tags: mysql, hibernate, view, mapping

Is it possible to make maps between beans and views in Hibernate. If there is please someone give show me an example. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Hibernate doesn't care if the table is an actual table or a view. Just make sure to never update or create instances of such an entity, or mark it as [non updatable](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Immutable.html).

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Immutable.html

Comment: @JBNizet mind including that link in your answer so it's easier to find when landing at this answer? Because as soon as you say `or mark it as non updatable`, person's first thought is `what's he talking about?`